# drop down options from json using angularjs data type is appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

Populating select with JSON in AngularJS with ng-options,

```
<select id="routeName-{{$index}}" ng-model="row.routeName" ng-options="routeName.id as routeName.name for routeName in routeNames" ng-change="flowRootChange($index)" style="width: 115px;"></select>
```

input JSON is below:

```
scope.routeNames=[{"id":"1","name":"routeName1"},{"id":"2","name":"routeName2"}];
```

but in html displaying like below:

```
<select style="width: 115px;" ng-change="flowRootChange($index)" ng-options="routeName.id as routeName.name for routeName in routeNames" ng-model="row.routeName" id="routeName-0" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
   <option label="routeName1" value="string:1">routeName1</option>     
   <option label="routeName2" value="string:2">routeName2</option>
</select>
```

By reading the data using JQuery I'm getting `string:2` as output.

```
console.log($("#routeName-"+rowid +" :selected").val());
```

I can't use `ng-model`/`$scope.row.routeName` because this drop down is in Table.
How can i read selected value(without `string:`) without using split() method?.
I'm using 'AngularJS v1.4.8' varsion.

Comment: You can also use: `ng-options="routeName as routeName.name for routeName in routeNames track by routeName.id"`

Comment: @SujataChanda this is populating options fine but selected value not setting, below approach is working fine one i accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-repeat instead of ng-options

```
<select style="width: 115px;" ng-change="flowRootChange($index)" ng-model="row.routeName" >
   <option ng-repeat='routeName in routeNames' label="routeName{{ routeName.id  }}" value="{{ routeName.id }}">{{ routeName.name }}</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this one :-

```
<select style="width: 115px;" ng-change="flowRootChange($index)" ng-model="name" >
```

{{ routeName.name}}

Comment: please put detailed answer.